# Android Studio, libgdx.so: text relocations

Tags: java, android, text, libgdx, relocation

I'm using android studio and game works well on my xperia tipo (android 4.0.4 ) but when I install it on my Xperia Z3+ ( android 7 ) and I get error:

> Detected problems with app native libraries
>
> (please consult log for detail): 
>    libgdx.so: text relocations

and error log is like this:

```
04-07 20:39:02.557 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.557 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.557 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.557 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.582 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.582 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.582 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.582 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.599 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.599 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.599 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.599 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.854 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.854 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.854 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
04-07 20:39:02.854 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
04-07 20:39:02.868 10411-10411/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 8, mPlayer(0xdce071e0)
04-07 20:39:03.696 10411-10945/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-07 20:39:03.707 10411-10945/com.tetovadeveloper.majmuni E/chromium: [ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
```

any help will be very appreciated :)